# iOS- All appicon & launcher sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I want know all sizes of app icon & app launcher

[image]

I go to site that create al sizes at one 
http://www.appiconsizes.com/
But I don't know how to add them to my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mentioned website seems to be offline. For doing that I usually use this website: http://makeappicon.com It will give you an `AppIcon.appiconset` just put this folder in your .xcassets folder though the finder.

Comment: Thank you its really helpful , the luncher images the same